# Conexión a 2 bases de datos en distintos servidores SQL SERVER

Tags: javascript, sql, nodejs

Buenos días: Estoy conectando una aplicación a 2 bases de datos diferentes alojadas en distintos servidores (SQL SERVER). El problema que estoy teniendo es al cerrar la conexión a la primera para ingresar a la segunda. Al no cerrar la conexión no me reconoce el insert en la tabla de la segunda base de datos.

Estoy utilizando sql.close() para cerrar las conexiones una vez terminada cada función, pero no me funciona.

```
const getAsiento = async (req,res) =>{
    const pool = await getConnection();
    const result = await pool.request().query(querys.getAsiento)
    var a = result.recordset[0]
    asiento = a.jobid
    sql.close();
   
}

const updateAsiento = async (req,res) =>{
    const pool = await getConnection();
    const result = await pool.request().query(querys.updateAsiento)
    update = true
    sql.close();
}

const conectar = async (stn_cam, etiqueta1, asiento) => {
    const pool = await getConnectionDTA();
    const result = await pool.request()
    .input("stn_cam", sql.VarChar, stn_cam)
    .input("cam", sql.VarChar, etiqueta1)
    .input("jobid", sql.Int, asiento)
    .query(querys.cargarNombre);
    sql.close();    
    console.log('Cargado en tabla');
}
```

Las funciones getAsiento y updateAsiento se ejecutan en la BD del primer servidor y la función conectar en la BD del segundo servidor.

Y en este orden las estoy ejecutando en la función principal:

```
function iniciar(){
    webcam.list(function (list) { 
        var webcam1 = NodeWebcam.create({device: list[0],frames: 60, width: 960, height: 540,quality:80, delay:2})
        var webcam2 = NodeWebcam.create({device: list[5],frames: 25, width: 1600, height: 896})
        try {
            getAsiento();
            var horaFinal = obtenerHora();
            if(asiento != 0){
                var etiqueta1 = asiento + '_Camera1_' + horaFinal;
                var etiqueta2 = asiento + '_Camera2_' + horaFinal;
        
                updateAsiento();

                webcam1.capture(`./images/${etiqueta1}.${opts.output}`, (err, data) => {
                    if(!err) {
                        console.log('Imagen creada:', etiqueta1)
                    }else{
                        console.log(err)
                    };
                });
                webcam2.capture(`./images/${etiqueta2}.${opts.output}`, (err, data) => {
                    if(!err) {
                        console.log('Imagen creada:', etiqueta2)
                    }else{
                        console.log(err)
                    };
                });
            }                  
        } catch (err) {
            iniciar()
        }
    conectar(stn_cam, etiqueta1, asiento);
    asiento = 0;
    }
)};
```

El error que me arroja es en la función conectar, porque no reconoce la tabla, me aparece que sigo conectado en el primer servidor. ¿Qué me está faltando realizar? O de que manera tengo que cerrar la conexión a la primera BD?